# Unity: Ошибка округления

Tags: unity3d, round

Пытаюсь создать карандаш как в Paint, а пользователь может выбрать размер карандаша. Если диаметр карандаша 1 всё идеально, а вот с 2 начинается непонятная ситуация, как на картинке.

[image]

Проблема в том что принцип работы карандаша должен быть вот таким. Допустим у меня радиус рисования 1. То есть карандаш должен рисовать на тех пикселях у которых центр находится внутри круга с радиусом 1px. А центр круга там где нажал пользователь. Более понятное объяснение на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это мой код

```cs
int diameter = (int)PencilSize.value;
for (int radius = 0; radius * 2 <= diameter; radius++)
{
    for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++)
    {
        float x = OnPixel().x + radius * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float y = OnPixel().y + radius * Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        int drawX = (int)Mathf.Round(x);
        int drawY = (int)Mathf.Round(y);

        if (IsPixel(drawX, drawY))
        {
            WorkshopScript.SelectedLayer.SetPixel(drawX, drawY, ColorsScript.GetColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `OnPixel()` показывает на каких координатах мышка (тип Vector2). Он работает правильно, проверено 100 раз. Я понимаю что у меня ошибка в округлении.
*Как исправить эту ошибку?*

---

П.Н.
Если понадобится вот ещё метод `OnPixel`.

```cs
public Vector2 OnPixel()
{
    Vector2 canvasMousePosition = new Vector2
    (
        Input.mousePosition.x - WorkshopScript.Canvas.transform.position.x + WorkshopScript.Canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width / 2,
        Input.mousePosition.y - WorkshopScript.Canvas.transform.position.y + WorkshopScript.Canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height / 2
    );
    Vector2 onPixel = new Vector2(canvasMousePosition.x / WorkshopScript.pixelLength, canvasMousePosition.y / WorkshopScript.pixelLength);
    return onPixel;
}
```

`PencilSize` это slider который определяет диаметр карандаша.
`IsPixel` это метод который проверяет есть ли в текстуре такой пиксель.
`WorkshopScript.SelectedLayer` это та текстура на котором можно рисовать.
`ColorsScript.GetColor()` это метод который возвращает выбранный пользователем цвет.

Comment: Попробуйте для округления вместо Round использовать Ceil

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Тоже самое

Comment: Unity3D я не знаю, но вот такой цикл for (float radius = 0; radius <= diameter / 2; radius++) выглядит очень странно для меня. Цикл с инкрементом по float?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов я бы поставил его int но диаметр может быть 1 а 1/2=0,5 поэтому чтобы ошибок не было сделал float

Comment: кстати, `for (int radius, radius * 2 <= diameter; radius++)` и никаких флоатов не нужно

Comment: Так может тогда вместо for  использовать while? И инкрементировать радиус внутри цикла с неким шагом? Либо как предложил rollingchar.

Comment: @trollingchar хорошо

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов изменил на int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for (int radius = 0; radius * 2 <= diameter; radius++)
> {
>     for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++)
>     {
> ```

Вот в этом-то и проблема. Вы перебираете не сами пиксели, а отвязанные от них точки, которые еще и распределены неравномерно (тем плотнее чем ближе к центру). У вас будет из-за и еще один баг - при очень большом радиусе некоторые пиксели не закрасятся.

Вам нужно обходить все пиксели в ограничивающем прямоугольнике области закрашивания, и сравнивать квадрат расстояния от центра с квадратом радиуса который дан.

Вот работающий код

```cs
int diameter = (int)PencilSize.value;
float radius = (float)diameter / 2;

for (float y = OnPixelInt().y - radius + 0.5f; y <= OnPixelInt().y + radius + 0.5f; y++)
{
    for (float x = OnPixelInt().x - radius + 0.5f; x <= OnPixelInt().x + radius + 0.5f; x++)
    {
        float distance = Mathf.Sqrt
        (
            Mathf.Pow(OnPixel().x - x, 2) +
            Mathf.Pow(OnPixel().y - y, 2)
        );

        if (distance <= radius)
        {
            if (IsPixel((int)x, (int)y))
            {
                WorkshopScript.SelectedLayer.SetPixel((int)x, (int)y, ColorsScript.GetColor());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А это не будет лагать если например будет 10000 пикселей? Ну или у меня максимальный размер 1000 x 1000 выдержит ли это процессор?

Comment: 10000 пикселей это квадрат 100x100, ваш метод для него сделает 100*360=36000 итераций, так что мой оптимальнее. Если надо *еще* быстрее, смотрите в сторону Quadtree.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Я сейчас попробую ваш совет и если проблем не будет поставлю галочку.

Comment: Проблемы могут быть на большой толщине карандаша, но там понадобится оптимизация уже другого рода

Comment: Идеально работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @Alt_F4 кстати можете отредактировать мой ответ добавив работающий код, а то я слишклм ленив для этого

Comment: @Alt_F4 и кстати, метод SetPixels будет работать на порядок эффективнее чем SetPixel в цикле, если конечно сможете разобраться

Comment: Не использовал SetPixels но посмотрю

Comment: некоторые недостатки есть исправлю и оставлю код

Comment: Я хочу попозже кинуть. Потому что я уже 7 часов сижу за Unity и у меня голова уже не работает.

Comment: Не разрешили модераторы мне изменить ваш ответ